# Совместить на одной координатной плоскости графики с разной размерностью

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на одной координатной плоскости совместить графики разной размерности (разное число точек, по которым выстраивается график).
Данные для графиков представлены в следующем виде:
Для первого графика беру столбцы датафрейма report и date, в файле 3962 объектов:

```
like,comment,repost,date

20,0,0,1488313047

.....

13,1,0,1488313110
```

Для второго графика также беру report и date, но в файле 33301 объект (данные имеют тот же вид в csv-файле).

Вот так предполагаю заполнить массив для оси X (даты в unix):

```
#заполнение оси X для нескольких графиков
start_date = 1488322544 #01/03/2017 01:55:44
end_date = 1495309932 #20/05/2017 22:52:12    
date_x = np.arange(start_date,end_date+1,1)
x = pd.to_datetime(date_x, unit='s')
```

Но дальше не могу наложить на эти X реальные значения для У из файла (их количество не совпадает).

```
yrepost1 = pd.read_csv(r'csvpostsdata_14795584.txt', usecols=['repost'])
yrepost2 = pd.read_csv(r'csvpostsdata_29428419.txt', usecols=['like'])
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title(u'Comparing groups activity by reports')
plt.plot(x,yrepost1,'b-',x,yrepost2,'g-')
plt.show()
```

Понимаю, что код неправильный (пытаюсь сопоставить большее количество значений оси X меньшему количеству значений Y) - об этом же говорит и ошибка

```
 "x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (6987389,) and (3962, 1)".
```

Вариант "дополнить входные данные рандомными значениями" не подходит.
Есть идея "сначала сформировать координатную плоскость с исчерпывающим количеством значений по оси X, а на нее добавлять графики". Реально ли это и как реализовать это в коде?

Comment: т.к. график кусочный получится, то, может быть, можно вывести отдельные точки на координатную плоскость?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib` пытается нарисовать график функции по данным точкам (X, Y), соединив соседние точки.

[**Функция** - в математике соответствие между элементами двух множеств, установленное по такому правилу, что **каждому элементу** одного множества ставится в соответствие некоторый элемент из другого множества](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))

Поэтому `matplotlib` отказывается рисовать график.

Вы должны указать соответствующие `X` значения для **каждого** графика:

```
plt.plot(df1.date, df1.repost, 'b-',
         df2.date, df2.repost, 'g-')
plt.legend(['df1','df2'])
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно каждый DataFrame должен иметь либо свой набор дат либо вам понядобятся два вектора дат (значений `X`) для каждого значения `Y` соответствующей длины.

PS для построений я использовал следующие данные:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='99999S', periods=1000),
                    'repost':np.random.randint(100, size=(1000))})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='99999S', periods=50),
                    'repost':np.random.randint(100, size=(50))})
```

Comment: за отсылку к матчасти и ответ большое спасибо!